# Union of dataframes in R by rownames

Tags: r, dataframe, union

I have 4 dataframes, each the index in a list. I would like to combine them altogether as one dataframe. In set language from mathematics, it would make most sense for this to be the union on the rownames. So I might have something like this:

```
U <- union(dfSub[[1]], dfSub[[2]], dfSub[[3]], dfSub[[4]])
```

The problem with the `union` function is that it operates only on vectors. How can I get this to work on dataframes?

1. How can I translate this into R?
2. Is there a better way of achieving the desired result?

**EDIT:** How can I preserve rownames after the union?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that shows what you're trying to preserve?

Comment: at the minimum, `lapply(dfSub, row names)` or if it is too much, `str(lapply(dfSub, row names))`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, bind them together:

```
df.cat <- rbind(dfSub[[1]], dfSub[[2]], dfSub[[3]], dfSub[[4]])
```

or better:

```
df.cat <- do.call(rbind, dfSub[1:4])
```

This first step requires that all data.frames have the same column names. If it is not the case, then you might be interested in the `rbind.fill` function from the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
df.cat <- rbind.fill(dfSub[1:4])
```

---

Then, to remove duplicates if you need (as a set union would):

```
df.union <- unique(df.cat)
```

Comment: how do I get the rownames to correspond?

Comment: To clarify, how do I get the rownames to be preserved? A cheap solution could be to add a column in each dataframe with the rowname.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus Can't you answer that yourself by actually trying this?

Comment: It does the union fine, but the rownames are not preserved. I need the rownames to be preserved.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus. What are your current rownames like? `lapply(dfSub, rownames)`?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus I would have thought that after the nth question you've asked where you're having specific problems getting row names to serve the purpose you want, that you'd have gotten the message and started using columns in data frames by now, since it has been suggested multiple times now.

Comment: @joran Are you saying I should use a column for the name instead of rownames()?

Answer (score -2):

You can combine dataframes with the [merge](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/merge.html) function.  Since you have multiple dataframes you can use [Reduce](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) to merge them all at once.

```
merged.data <- Reduce(function(...) merge(...), list(dfSub[[1]], dfSub[[2]], dfSub[[3]], dfSub[[4]])
```

As an example:

```
> people <- c('Bob', 'Jane', 'Pat')
> height <- c(72, 64, 68)
> weight <- c(220, 130, 150)
> age <- c(45, 32, 35)
> height.data <- data.frame(people, height)
> weight.data <- data.frame(people, weight)
> age.data <- data.frame(people, age)

> height.data
  people height
1    Bob     72
2   Jane     64
3    Pat     68
> weight.data
  people weight
1    Bob    220
2   Jane    130
3    Pat    150
> age.data
  people age
1    Bob  45
2   Jane  32
3    Pat  35


> Reduce(function(...) merge(...), list(height.data, weight.data, age.data))
  people height weight age
1    Bob     72    220  45
2   Jane     64    130  32
3    Pat     68    150  35
```

Comment: Will the rownames() from dfSub[[1]], dfSub[[2]], ... be present in the union?

Comment: The ellipses just take the arguments to the function and pass them along to the next function.  So, in this case Reduce expects the function to get an accumulator and a vector to accumulate.  It just passes the accumulator and the vector down into merge.

Comment: To whoever downvoted, can you explain why this answer is not useful?

Comment: @joneshf I am guessing they downvoted because the question is about a set union and your answer is like a join