# Adding data to column dependent on match

Tags: r, merge, union

I am trying to merge data from one dataframe to another. I suppose this is an easy question for everybody here. But I cant seem to get the right result. So something like.

```
df1 <- data.frame(X=c("aap","rel","kop"), Y=c(500,12,350))
df2 <- data.frame(X=c("lee","1su","eeu","ggu", "ees"), Y=c(100,12,350,80,50)) 
df3 <- merge(df1, df2)
```

The result should be:

```
df3 <- data.frame(X=c("aap","rel","kop", "lee","1su","eeu","ggu", "ees"), 
                 Y=c(500,12,350,100,12,350,80,50)
```

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408225/union-of-dataframes-in-r-by-rownames

Comment: How is this question related to "dependent on match" as included in the title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for

```
rbind(df1, df2)

    X   Y
1 aap 500
2 rel  12
3 kop 350
4 lee 100
5 1su  12
6 eeu 350
7 ggu  80
8 ees  50
```